# Facebook SDK (4.15.1) crashes on Login (iOS8)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated Facebook SDK(4.15.1) in my app. For iOS9 my app works properly and doesn't crash on user login. If I run the same app on iOS8 device and try to login then app crashes saying:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: logging_token)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x294ad45f 0x37343c8b 0x293cac53 0x11941f 0x119909 0x1198a5 0x123bcb 0x11980b 0x119741 0x1185cf 0x115571 0x2c9fae7f 0x2c9fae21 0x2c9e5c43 0x2c9fa88d 0x2c9fa567 0x2c9f3e31 0x2c9ca759 0x2cc3e2f9 0x2c9c91a9 0x29473fbf 0x294733cf 0x29471a35 0x293bf3b1 0x293bf1c3 0x309ec201 0x2ca2943d 0x976f0 0x378cfaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have cross checked my info.plist and observed all everything is Configured properly.

Comment: check your **logging_token** has empty or nil

Comment: Where should I check for logging_token ? I have checked the Plist , found it is configured properly for Facebook SDK(SDK works properly for ios9)   @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: have you got any solutions shailesh? i have a same problem.

Comment: @ShaileshChandavar 
It works fine on xcode 7.3.1 - tested on iOS 8.4 device
Haven't tested for xcode 8.x versions yet.

Comment: @ShaileshChandavar did you or anybody else find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Looking for a solution as well...

Comment: Facing same issue. Not able to login on iOS8.1